# Convert NSString to NSDate with am/pm and timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

My input `NSString` is `2017-01-11 5:33:55 am +0000`. And my codes are:

```
    date = @"2017-01-11 5:33:55 am +0000";
    uploadFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a Z";
    [uploadFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    NSDate *theDate = [uploadFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

But the returned `NSDate` are always `2017-01-11 0:33:55 UTC` regardless of the input hour. It means if input is `2017-01-11 3:33:55 am +0000`, the result is also the same.

Does anyone has encounter the problem before? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: `HH` is four hour in 24h format, but since you have am/pm, it's clearly 12 hour format. So at least change `HH` with `hh`.

Comment: @Larme it exactly fix the issue. Could you help to post the comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks a lot! It save my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HH` is four hour in 24h format, but since you have "am"/"pm", it's clearly 12h format. 
Change `HH` with `hh` in your `dateFormat`.

Keep in mind the doc available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) for the format, which for iOS7+ is 
[here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Use this date Format :

```
[uploadFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a Z"];
```